# Loading dynamically 3d models before the react app launches

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using r3f to load 3d models dynamically from a list.

It's a slider so when I click on the arrow, it changes the information and show another 3d models.

[screen of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE2Z5.jpg)

The problem is that it seems that it loads the 3d models only when it will be visible.

I would like to use my custom loader to load my three 3d models before the app launches, so I dont have this laggy moment when my animation runs.

How can I achieve that ?

Some infos that could be important :

- My loader is in index.html, not sure it it's the best solution.
- I'm using motion framer if maybe there is behavior that I dont know

```
//Watch.jsx
import {useGLTF, Stage, PresentationControls} from "@react-three/drei";
import {useLoader} from "@react-three/fiber";


import React, { useRef} from 'react';


import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";


 function Watch(props){
const watchRef = useRef();

 
    function Scene(){
        const gtlf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, props.url)
       
        const clockRef = useRef()
        return <primitive ref={clockRef} object={gtlf.scene}  /> 
    }


    return(
        <PresentationControls 
speed={1.5} 
zoom={1}
polar={[-0.1, Math.PI / 4]}
>

<Stage >
    <mesh ref={watchRef} {...props} />
<Scene />
</Stage>

</PresentationControls>
    )

}


export default Watch;
```

```
//CanvasWatch.jsx
import {Canvas, useLoader} from "@react-three/fiber";
import './canvasWatch.css'
import {Suspense} from 'react';
import Watch from "./Watch";


import React, { useRef} from 'react';

import {motion} from "framer-motion"
  
function CanvasWatch(props){
 
  return (
    <motion.div className="container-watch-animation">
     
    <Canvas 
    dpr={[1,2]} 
  >
     <Suspense fallback={null}>
    <Watch url={props.url} />
    </Suspense>
  </Canvas>
 
  
   </motion.div>
  );

}
    
  
    export default CanvasWatch;
```

```
//Slide.jsx
<motion.div
        className="watch-slider-container"
        variants={containerVariants3}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="visible"
      >
        <div className="slider-controls">
          <div className="arrow-group">
            <motion.img
              onClick={backSlide}
              src="/arrow.png"
              alt=""
              className="arrow-top"
            />
            <motion.img
              onClick={nextSlide}
              src="/arrow.png"
              alt=""
              className="arrow-bot"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="numbers">
            <div className="slide-circle selected-circle"></div>
            <div className="slide-circle"></div>
            <div className="slide-circle"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="watch-3d-container">
          <CanvasWatch url={watches[sliderState].url} />
        </div>
      </motion.div>
```

Thanks for the help

I tried to use the loader directly with react component but it didnt work as well